# Update Xcode 8.3.2 compiler error after update from xcode 8.2: command failed due to signal: illegal instruction 4

Tags: firebase, swift3, compiler-errors, xcode8

Update: I build my project in Firebase 3 and Xcode 8.2. Yesterday I installed Xcode 8.3.2 and updated the pods of Firebase to 4.0. Of course I updated the code as well so it is working with firebase 4.0 (in xcode 8.2.1)

In xcode 8.3.2 (also 8.3.3) I can not compile the project anymore. The error message is:

Command failed due to signal: illegal instruction 4

This same error is pointing at 9 different Viewcontrollers (which work perfectly fine in xcode 8.2.1). There is no code highlighted that causes the error. That is the problem. Does anybody have experience with this type of general error?

[Printscreen of Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q8gA.png)

Comment: Without seeing the code and specifically which statements are causing the error, we would just be guessing so I would suggest including code and what lines are crashing. That being said, Firebase 4 changed the API so you will need to update your code accordingly. See [Migrate to the latest Firebase SDK for Swift (v4.0.0)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/naming-migration-guide)

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: Does your project build or does it crash when you run it?

Comment: It does not build at all.

Comment: @Jay: what is in your opinion the best way to find the issue?

Comment: Tough one.. I would start by looking at the minimum build settings for your project. i.e. if it's set to 10.6 (for example) some piece of your code won't work with 10.6 and would generate that compiler error.

Comment: Have you read the documentation of the migration of Firebase SDK for Swift? And have you tried to clean and rebuild the project? If you are using FirebaseUI, it might be possible it is not yet compatible with Firebase 4. If you have tried all of that, did you try to downgrade Firebase 4 to Firebase 3. Let me know when/how you have fixed it!